# Stop iCloud Password Popups in Yosemite

Tags: icloud

Is there a way to disable this without signing out of iCloud? I don't remember my password. Everyday I get a bunch of iCloud popups and it's kind of annoying.

Thank you!

Comment: You can’t be signed into iCloud if it’s asking you for a password.  Why not reset the password and fix the problem?

Comment: I am signed in but it keeps asking me to re-enter the password which I forgot. Already tried that and it didn't work. Just wanna stop these annoying popups.

Comment: can you disable individual services in iCloud preferences?  @macnoobie888 Never seen Yosemite, so idk